How to evaluate this integral : $\Omega =\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^{a-1}(x)\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(x)} dx $
How to evaluate this integral :
$$\Omega =\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^{a-1}(x)\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(x)} dx $$
where :$$a>0$$
If $a=1$:
$$\Omega = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
If $a=2$
$$\Omega = 2\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\cos^2(x) dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
by using mathematica
If $a=1/3$
$$\Omega =\frac{\pi}{2}$$
If $a=3/2$
$$\Omega =\frac{\pi}{2}$$
I think that
$$\Omega =\frac{\pi}{2}$$
But I can't prove it. Can I find some help on how to prove it?

Hint: try writing $\sin(ax)$ as the imaginary part of the complex exponential $e^{iax}$.

How will this help you evaluate integration?

Also see this question. I added a second approach to my answer.

\begin{align}
&\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^{a-1}x\ \frac{\sin ax}{\sin x} dx \\
=& \ \Im \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{ \cos^{a-1}x}{\sin x}e^{i a x}dx \\
=& \  \Im \ \frac {1}{2^{a-1}}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{ (e^{i x} + e^{-ix})^{a-1} }{\sin x}e^{i a x}dx \\
= & \  \Im \ \frac {1}{2^{a-1}}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ \binom {a-1}k e^{i (2k+1)x}}{\sin x}dx \\
 = & \ \frac {1}{2^{a-1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty { \binom {a-1}k \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{\sin[(2k+1)x]}{\sin x}dx }\\
 = & \  \frac {1}{2^{a-1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom {a-1}k \frac\pi2 =\frac\pi2
\end{align}

Where does the $\Im$ go in the fourth line?

@Grey $ \Im \ e^{i (2k+1)x}=\sin[(2k+1)x]$

For non-integer $a$ as in the question, the generalized binomial series must be used (as in this answer) which has argument restrictions. Can you elaborate on this some more?
